# Decay Function for Years

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a decay function with the following properties :

1) Produce a value between 0 and 1

2) Would drop ~30% from 2019 to 2014 and have a near a near-constant decrease behavior after that till 1888.

Any hints on how build such a function would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What should the decrease rate be, between 2014 and 1888?

Comment: You might be able to fit [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz–Makeham_law_of_mortality) common model.

Comment: @MattiP. any near linear  decrease is fine right know, I still would need to play with the function to understand what is the best fit.

Comment: Is a piecewise function ok?